# How handle event click on callback when adding addEventListeners for all classes on document ready?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I want to check if div I click has a class called "mole". I add the a callback with a property event, when adding click addEventLister for all classes called "cell".

```
Game.prototype.checkClicks = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  if (e.classList.contains("mole")) {
    new Audio(self.baseUrl + self.audio[0]).play();
    self.score++;
    self.displayScore();
  } else {
    new Audio(self.baseUrl + self.audio[1]).play();
  }
};

const myAudio = document.createElement("audio");
myAudio.setAttribute("src", "./sounds/el_jarabe_tapatio.m4a");
myAudio.loop = true;

$(document).ready(function() {
  const moleGame = new Game();
  moleGame.startGame();
  const allCells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
  for (let i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) {
    allCells[i].addEventListener("click", moleGame.checkClicks(event));
  }
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at Game.checkClicks (main.js:110)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:128)
    at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

means, "e" the event is not defined.. I understand the click event is not defined on load, but only when I click on the div, but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `checkClicks` immediately instead of passing a function that'll be called when the event happens.

Furthermore, you're expecting a `classList` on an `event` object, which won't be there.

Lastly, you're using `self`, in an apparent hope that it will be referencing the `game` object.

Instead pass a function as the handler, use the `currentTarget` property of the `event` object, and use `this` instead of `self`.

```
Game.prototype.checkClicks = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains("mole")) {
    new Audio(this.baseUrl + this.audio[0]).play();
    this.score++;
    this.displayScore();
  } else {
    new Audio(this.baseUrl + this.audio[1]).play();
  }
};

const myAudio = document.createElement("audio");
myAudio.setAttribute("src", "./sounds/el_jarabe_tapatio.m4a");
myAudio.loop = true;

$(document).ready(function() {
  const moleGame = new Game();
  moleGame.startGame();
  const allCells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
  for (let i = 0; i < allCells.length; i++) {
    allCells[i].addEventListener("click", event => moleGame.checkClicks(event));
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the handler immediately, instead of passing the handler for execution later (when the event occurs). So remove the parentheses. The call will be made with the event object as argument:

```
allCells[i].addEventListener("click", moleGame.checkClicks);
```

If your `checkClicks` method relies on `this` being `moleGame` (which seems not to be the case), then do:

```
allCells[i].addEventListener("click", moleGame.checkClicks.bind(moleGame));
```

Note that although this will define `e`, the event object does not have a `classList` property. You maybe intended `e.target.classList`.

Comment: `event` objects don't have `classList`, `this` is the wrong thing to `.bind()`, and `self` won't have much meaning in his function.

Comment: True, `classList` is not in the event, but OP wanted to fix that the `e` event is not defined. We know not the context where `self` is defined, and binding `this` is no harm, ... I explained that this would be nice if you want it to refer to `moleGame`.

Comment: If it's true that the OP actually has a use for `self` instead of `this` in the function, which doesn't seem likely, then there' no reason to use `.bind()` anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I did not insist on that point. It was just a remark in case it would be useful to the OP.

Comment: Just be aware that the `this` you're binding is the `document`, so I'm not quite sure what you're getting at there.

Comment: Corrected. I intended to write `moleGame`.